# Webservice and FilterXML to pull data from website

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet that I have tried to "automate" in the past. The best response I got was to use VBA - tried, failed, even with all of the author's suggestions. Just recently I heard of this new function in 2013 version and want to know if I can incorporate it.

I am trying to pull the "XXXX mi" from this page (http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=sfo-JFK) using a formula.

Can anyone suggest the proper formula, I have scoured the blogs, the support pages, the YouTube videos, I am just not good with XML but this data is crucial to me. I even went into the source info for the page and used firebug on Mozilla, still am lost). The rest of the spreadsheet does all of the backwork (hyperlink, abbreviate airport, etc...) this is the one thing I have left to automate.

Any and all help appreciated.
Thanks a billion.

Comment: The data you are trying to read isn't well-formed XML so the "FilterXML" worksheet function isn't going to work

Answer (score 0):

The total distance is within the last <TD> element of the only <TABLE> within the <DIV> with an ID of *dist_body*.

```
Function total_distance(Optional qry As String = "SFO-JFK")
    Dim str As String, htmlBDY As Object
    
    On Error GoTo bm_Report_Error
    
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=" & qry, False
        .Send
        
        If .Status = "200" Then
            Set htmlBDY = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
            htmlBDY.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            With htmlBDY
                'the div as a unique ID
                With .getElementById("dist_body")
                    'should only be one table in this div
                    With .getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
                        'get the last TD in this table
                        With .getElementsByTagName("td")(.getElementsByTagName("td").Length - 1)
                            str = .innerText
                            GoTo bm_Exit_Function
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        Else
            str = "Error: " & .Status
            GoTo bm_Exit_Function
        End If
        
    End With

GoTo bm_Exit_Function

bm_Report_Error:
    str = Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

bm_Exit_Function:
    total_distance = str
End Function
```

I've tried to minimize var sets and assignments as much as possible.

[image: Airport Mileage reporter]

Remember that you are pulling in a non-breaking space (e.g.  `) between the numerical distance and the *mi* label.

Comment: Wow, not even going to pretend to understand that. I will check this once I am home, But I will just assume it works - any options changes I need to make to Excel to enable the code to run properly? Thanks again!